# Group dataframe by week and get min and max dates within a week to new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which includes columns "call_date", which is date of call and "call_week", which is number of week (week does not necessarily start on Monday or Sunday and does not necessarily last exactly 7 days):

[image]

What I want to do is add new column to dataframe which would contain boundary dates of week separated by " - ". For example, if we have a `WEEK` 68 which has minimum `CALL_DATE` of `2019-04-25` and maximum `CALL_DATE` of `2019-04-30`, new column should contain value `2019-04-25 - 2019-04-30`.

I tried:
`dfg = df.groupby('WEEK')['CALL_DATE'].agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index()`

`dfg`:

[image]

Then I added those min and max columns to `df` via `join`:

`df = df.join(dfg, lsuffix = 'WEEK', rsuffix = 'WEEK')`

Now I am trying to apply `lambda` function to concatenate those columns in one which contains the result:

`df['WEEK_TEXT'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['min'].strftime("%d.%m.%Y") + ' - ' + x['max'].strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))`

But I get an error: `KeyError: ('min', 'occurred at index CONTACT_ID')`

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['WEEK_TEXT'] = df['min'].dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") + ' - ' + df['max'].dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

In your solution is necessary `axis=1` for processes by rows:

```
f = lambda x : x['min'].strftime("%d.%m.%Y") + ' - ' + x['max'].strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
df['WEEK_TEXT'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for quick response and solution! My bad, I forgot the parameter ```axis=1```